# Bluetooth driver code 10 device cannot start in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

Recently my Bluetooth driver has abruptly stopped working.

It is an Intel Wireless Bluetooth and it displays this error:

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)

STATUS_DEVICE_POWER_FAILURE
```

My attempted solutions:

- Reinstalled my driver (several times) in Device Manager and also used [Intel Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html).
- Restarted all Bluetooth services in Services and set them to automatic startup then restarted my computer.
- Uninstalled my Bluetooth driver and restarted my computer, but it still was still not fixed.
- Used the Windows Bluetooth troubleshoot, but it didn't say that I needed a Bluetooth driver update.

After all of these attempts, it would still return and display Code (10). Occasionally, the Device Manager window would quickly flicker the Bluetooth from working to display the error message before finally stopping on the error message. I am also not using a USB device to connect for Bluetooth. All of the troubleshooting options that I have used say that my Bluetooth driver is up to date and does not require an update. Windows Defender Security Center also detected an issue with the "Device Performance & Health" but its troubleshooter only asked me to restart my computer which did not work.

I am on a Windows 10 computer. This was not the result of a Windows update.

Comment: Error 10 usualy appears if you have 2 (or more) Bluetooth hardware (dongles or built-in) connected. So one is running and other(s) has/have error 10. However you wrote that you do not use any USB dongle. Based on this I can guess that this is 2 in one internal card (Bluetooth + WiFi). You probably may need filter driver from the vendor to get it working correctly. Even you have drivers installed you have to install filter driver as well.